Prove $80^{\circ}$ is not a constructible angle
Prove that $\theta = 80^{\circ}$ is not constructible using a straightedge and a compass.
I frequently see this accomplished by first finding the minimal polynomial $m_{\cos(80^{\circ}),\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ (via the triple angle formula). Since $\cos(80^{\circ})$ is not constructible, neither is $80^{\circ}$. What would an alternate approach be?

A usual proof that trisection is impossible with straight-edge and compasses does it by showing that $20^\circ$ is not constructible (but since $60^\circ$ is constructible, trisection is not possible).  So if we construct $80^\circ$, bisecting twice would give us $20^\circ$, contradiction.

Admittedly, the $20^\circ$ proof uses the "minimal polynomial" approach.

Suppose $80^{\circ}$ is constructible. Then, $40^{\circ}$ is constructible, since we can bisect angles. Recall that the internal angles of a regular $9$-gon are $360^{\circ}/9 = 40 ^{\circ}$. In order to construct the regular 9-gon we would need the primitive ninth roots of unity via $\zeta_9$, which is constructible only if $[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2^k$ for some $k$. Yet, $$ [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9) : \mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(9) = \lvert \{1,2,4,5,7,8 \} \rvert = 6 \neq 2^k$$ for any integral power. Thus, we cannot construct $\zeta_9$, meaning we cannot construct the regular $9$-gon, so we cannot construct $40^{\circ}$, giving us our contradiction.

+1 A good answer.  But needs references?

Thanks! I added some references to pages including the relevant results used in the anwer.
